# front-load clothes washers with easy access to drain pump

Tags: washing-machine

This is a question asked from the perspective of wanting to be able to do a DIY job a little more easily when the time comes...

Our current washer has to be completely taken apart —rear panel, top panel, intelligence board, door, front panel, and some other stuff— in order to get access to the pump.

Are there front-loader washers that provide a simple access panel to the pump, or locate the pump located where it can be easily reached when only the rear-panel is removed?

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Some front loaders (and some top loaders like my last one) havel a small round access panel in the front panel to access the pump - usually lower left or right - easily seen if you look...

Comment: Access to the filter is not access to the pump.